# How to set Perl Global Enviorment Variable (Windows)

Tags: windows, perl

How it is possible to call "perl" from anywhere in CMD.exe, since by default it will only call from System32 or the install directory of perl

E.g. so I can open a cmd window at "C:\test" and I will be able to call perl

Comment: Which perl do you have? StrawberryPerl? ActivePerl?

Answer (score 0):

Set the PATH env variable to include the path to your perl exe?